# Reset sudoers file

Tags: sudo, visudo

I want to add a new user to run all commands without a password, so I went to edit `/etc/sudoers` (using visudo of course) by adding the line `myuser ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`.

Everything is OK, but 15 minutes later, the file sudoers was reset to original. It means the sudoers file didn't have anything that I had typed in it previously.

Ex: the first sudoers:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL  
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL  
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

After adding line:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL  
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL  
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL  
myuser ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But 15 minutes later:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL  
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL  
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

So why does it have to be reset after 15 minutes and how to fix it?

Comment: The command is supposed to be `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` Try adding this to the sudoers file instead

Comment: Are you saving, closing _and exiting_ `visudo` or are you leaving it open?

Comment: i have added line: "username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" or anything, (after edit the sudoers file, i type :wq to save it) file sudoers was still reset after 15 minutes.